# need for allocating memory of ofstream pointer

Tags: c++, io

In this program:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
   std::ofstream *fb;
   (*fb).open("file.txt",std::ios::out);

   std::cout.rdbuf((*fb).rdbuf());

   std::cout<<"Hello World to ALL";

   return 0;
}
```

On running it gives **segmentation fault** - so on changing `*fb` to `fb` helps as no space was allocated

But what I don't understand is why does an `ofstream` object requires a space to be allocated if the memory which it needs to handled (`file.txt`) is already there? Shouldn't it be like the way file I/O is handled in **C** language where a `FILE` pointer is used to open and then the operations are performed without allocating any memory?

Plus what will the **allocated memory** using `ofstream` pointer functionally (theoraticaly) signify?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer?

Comment: `fb` isn't a pointer to the file. It's a pointer to the file reader.

Comment: An instance of an `std::ofstream` will have a buffer for efficient writing, and some other meta-information about the state.

Comment: `std::ofstream *fb;` is an uninitialized pointer. It doesn't point to an `std::ofstream`. It's a hard rule in C++ that you cannot dereference an uninitialized pointer. Even if `std::ofstream` was stateless and didn't need any memory you still couldn't do `*fb` or `fb->`. `fopen` returns a valid pointer, it isn't a member of the `FILE*` pointer so the two aren't comparable here.

Comment: C *also* allocates memory — the `fopen` call allocates the necessary memory for the `FILE` structure and returns a pointer to it. Same thing in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never creates a `std::ofstream` object. You can't call `open` on a `std::ofstream` object before you create one.

You create a variable of the type to hold a pointer to a `std::ofstream` object, but you don't actually make it point to anything. So when you call `open` on the object it points to, you aren't calling `open` on any valid object at all.

> But what I don't understand is why does an ofstream object requires a space to be allocated if the memory which it needs to handled (file.txt) is already there?

It's not just that you didn't allocate space. Even if you have space for an object, it still has to be initialized to valid contents for an object of that type. The space is needed to hold state information such as whether the file is open or not. And it has to hold valid contents, not garbage, or it may say the file is open when it isn't.

> Shouldn't it be like the way file I/O is handled in C language where a FILE pointer is used to open and then the operations are performed without allocating any memory?

The `fopen` function allocates memory, makes its contents valid, and returns a pointer to it to you. You then have to be sure to call `fclose` to clean that up when you are done. You can write equivalent functions for `std::ofstream` if you want, but then you will lose the benefit of many C++ features such as RAII.